# Number Formats for different locales in Excel (OOXML)

Tags: excel, ms-office, openxml, number-formatting, date-formatting

In the ISO/IEC 29500-1 Part 1 Section 18.8.30, the documentation presents us with the built in numFmt (number formats) used by excel whose format code is implied and not explicitly stored.

These Format codes are provided for the en-US locale.

Where can we find the format codes for rest of the locales?

For eg: numFmtId 14 - m/d/yy (in en-US locale) and - yyyy/m/d (in ja-JP locale)

This changing behaviour can be noticed with all the implied number formats in different locales. Sometimes there would be language difference, sometimes some characters are Uppercase/Lowercase difference, etc.

I am developing a parsing application which allows to import an excel file and display the information present in the file. The application is on C++ platform.

Is there a way to track all these changes and have a complete list for all the locales and the formats used?

I have already gone through the all 4 parts of the ISO/IEC 29500, MS-XLSX, MS-OI29500 documentations. It is possible that the answer might be in one of these and I might have missed it but I think that is highly unlikely.

I want to know how to format a given built in format when opened in some different locale than the original. (I create a workbook in en-US locale with a date which has numFmtId = 14. The format of the string will change if i open this workbook in ja-JP locale. I want to know how to change the format to the new locale so that the date is in the correct format according to locale. The documentations only give the formatting rules for en-US locale)

Comment: Why do you need these? Perhaps you could just make use of the Application.International properties to determine what is being used on the current machine?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No, that wouldnt be of much help. It will tell me information such as use comma (,) as a thousands separator in US locale and dot (.) in the German locale but not how the format changes. 
I have edited the question to provide a bit more clarity on my question.